# ffmpeg stops streaming if one input stops

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I am trying to create a mpeg-ts stream where video is a screengrab from Xvfb and audio is from internet radio (mp3 or aac stream). It works reasonably well, but if there is a problem with the internet radio, then the whole output stops, not just audio and does not resume until I kill ffmpeg and start it again.

Here is the command line I am using

`DISPLAY=:1 ffmpeg -re -video_size 768x576 -framerate 50 -f x11grab -i :1 -i http://internet-radio/mp3 -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 6000k -minrate 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 3000k -dc 10 -top 0 -f mpegts  -c:a mp2 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -flags +ilme+ildct -vf "tinterlace=interleave_top" udp://192.168.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316`

Is there a way to either prevent it from stalling (just produce silence until the audio input returns) or at least detect that it has failed so I can write a script to restart it?

Comment: from the fairly extensive research i've done, ffmpeg is a synchronous process, so when one of your inputs stops, it stops reading the other.  My guess is that you will have to write some sort of buffering program that will receive the audio and relay it to ffmpeg, and then that program would autodetect when incoming audio stops, and relay silence to ffmpeg instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *apad* audio filter to extend the stream with indefinite silence. You should be able to either add an *-af* command to your existing string...

```
-vf "[0]tinterlace=interleave_top" -af "[1]apad"
```

...or change your existing *-vf* string to *-filter_complex* to handle both the audio and video filtering commands...

```
-filter_complex "[0]tinterlace=interleave_top;[1]apad"
```

Note that the input stream specifiers ("[0]" for the x11grab and "[1]" for the audio stream) **should be** optional, but some older versions of FFmpeg can confuse themselves if they're not specified.

If neither filter setup work as-is, you may need to add the *-shortest* flag into your general output params as well (not as part of the filter string, mind you), e.g.:

```
-filter_complex "[0]tinterlace=interleave_top;[1]apad" -shortest
```